# SSRS max upload size limitations

Tags: ssrs

We are working on a WiX project for deploying our large application (the server side of the application, that is.) The customer has the choice to have the application server, the SQL Server and the Reporting Server all on the same box, on 2 boxes or on 3 separate boxes (or VM's.)

Here is one of our current issues that we are working through. For the SSRS side, we have a main model that we need to deploy that is about 7mb. With the default install of SSRS, the max is 4mb. I know that we need to manually manipulate the two web.config files to add the 'maxRequestLength' string, but we don't really want to do this on their servers and that is assuming that this meets the clients security policies as well as that they aren't already setting that to some other value for another application. (We can't assume that they are using that SSRS instance only for our application.)

Our customers are local City and County governments.

Is there any way to accomplish deploying the model file manually, bypassing the max upload size limitations?

-WC

Comment: can't you deploy through visual studio?

Comment: What do you mean? We are building the project in VS using WiX. The first step in the installer is checking for the existence of SQL Server, IIS, .Net and Reporting Services. That said, we need to see that they exist, but we can't assume that they are using the instances of these for our application only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding, This is a restriction specified on the server piece. So you would have to modify it's web.config to change the max upload size.  I'm not aware, although I could be wrong, of a way to change this setting through options within the reporting services management site.

You could ask your client to temporarily modify this.  Or ask them if they would be able to increase the max upload limit to 10mb.

Comment: Brandon, That is what my research has found too... We are trying to make it as 'out of the box' as possible, but this looks like it will have to be done as part of the pre-install preparations by the client.

Comment: I don't think it would be an unreasonable request.  4mb to 10mb is a pretty small jump.  You could also reference the following from the MSDN blogs if your client wants more info.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mariae/archive/2009/12/23/error-maximum-request-length-exceeded-in-reporting-services.aspx

Comment: I'm not worried about doing it manually... we do it this way now... but as we role out a new install package, it would be nice to have all these things done auto-magically.

Comment: It would be nice, but modifying a service level setting could introduce risk or worse liability.  

You could however have your install package check the setting as part of validation.  This could help prevent the install from just failing when uploading the file.